# Compare millions of records in different databases

Tags: sql-server

I am looking for a tool that will compare all the data within a database and will report back and discrepancies that it will find.

The reason I am looking for this tool is because our upline data processor is changing how they are generating their data and we will need to verify the accuracy of the changes by comparing every record and the associated fields.

We tried the Visual Studio data compare but found that to be pretty slow when comparing over 100k of records. So if anyone has a good/fast tool to do this please let me know. There are about 4 million records we would like to compare and if there are ways to set thresholds on the tool that would be great too :).

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a great tool: http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare/

in fact the whole suite is a must have if you do much DBA work.